# How to get service broker database queue status?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get service broker queue status (Enabled/Disabled) somehow programmatically. Either, T-SQL, PowerShell, etc.
I tried `$MyQueue = Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SQL\mydbserver\default\databases\MyQueue\ServiceBroker\Queues | where {$_.Name -like "MyQueue"}` but couldn’t find how to get the status.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PoSh just wraps SMO. [`ServiceQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.aspx) exposes [`IsEnqueueEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.isenqueueenabled.aspx) for queue status, [`IsActivationEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.isactivationenabled.aspx) for activation status,
[`IsRetentionEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.isretentionenabled.aspx) for retention status and finally [`IsPoisonMessageHandlingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.broker.servicequeue.ispoisonmessagehandlingenabled.aspx) for, well, poison message handling status.

Also [PoSh](https://twitter.com/rusanu/status/440500855070932994) has the habit of hiding properties. See [how to see all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259142/how-to-see-all-properties).

Comment: Id addition to Remus's answer, the t-sql equivalent is in sys.service_queues http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187795.aspx